# How to sum values from multiple features with a given attribute in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm working with two layers right now - a line layer called **Water Lines** and a polygon layer called **Land Areas**. The **Land Areas** layer has polygons in which water runoff occurs during precipitation events. That *Runoff Estimate* from each polygon feature is received by a *Receiving Water Line Feature*, which corresponds to a feature of the same name in the **Water Lines** layer.  A single Water Line feature can receive runoff from multiple Land Areas polygon features.

I want the field *Total Collected Runoff* for a given *Receiving Water Line Feature Name* in the **Water Lines** layer to sum the *Runoff Estimate* values for all polygons in the **Land Areas** layer with the matching Water Line Feature Name in the *Receiving Water Line Feature* field.

[image: Water Lines attribute table]

[image: Land Area attribute table]

Comment: A diagram or screenshot would sure help me understand what you need! Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression like this to update the field `Total Collected Runoff (gal)` of the layer `Water Lines`.

I took the field names currently displayed, but maybe there are aliases, so modify it in the expression if needed.

```sql
aggregate(
    layer:= 'Land Areas',
    aggregate:= 'sum',
    expression:= "Runoff Estimate (gallons)",
    filter:= "Receiving Water Line Feature" = attribute(@parent, 'Water Line Feature Name')
)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you